# Getting part of QString

Tags: c++, qt, indexof, qstring

How do I get value `"Recording.mp3"` from this `QString`

```
C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Temp/AudelloTemp/Recording.mp3
```

If I use `lastIndexof('/')` function then it searches backward for last occurrence

If I use `indexof('/')` function then it searches forward for first occurrence.

I am not getting any way to get it.

Or is the only way to use a loop to get that value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seeing as it's a file path and you're looking for the file name, the correct approach would be this:

```
// When you have this:
QString s("C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Temp/AudelloTemp/Recording.mp3");

// Do this:

QFileInfo f(s);
QString s1 = f.fileName();
// now s1 is "Recording.mp3"
```

Nevertheless, to answer your question as worded, the `QString` member function to use would be `lastIndexOf()`. You've misread the documentation: it doesn't "search backward for the last occurrence," it "looks for the last occurrence in the string, doing it by searching backwards." So in your case, it would indeed return the `/` separating `AudelloTemp` from `Recording.mp3`.

Answer (score -1):

How about:

```
QString filename_only(const QString& path)
{
  int index = path.lastIndexOf('/'); // check validity
  return path.right(path.size() - index); // Might be off by one, feel free to fix
}
```

I don't have Qt here now, so please check if I'm off-by-one.

Comment: Bad advice in light of there being `QFileInfo`. Homebrew path editing usually is broken in one way or another. In Qt, valid paths are separated by either '/' or `QDir::separator()` (the two can be the same on some platforms). Don't reimplement what's already there.